# Allow location android permission prompt not coming in ionic3 while using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()

Tags: geolocation, ionic3, android-permissions, androidsdk31, cordova-8.0.0

I want the location prompt while opening the app having options to Allow location while using the app etc.
Android permissions also applied in **config.xml**.I have applied the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION & ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION & ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS.